# How to get objectId immediately after save data with Parse and swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

```
    var cardObject = PFObject(className: "YourCard")
    cardObject["cardNumber"] = cardNumber
    cardObject["balance"] = balance
    cardObject["expire"] = date
    cardObject["validFlg"] = cardStatus
    cardObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if (success != nil) {
            NSLog("Object created with id: \(cardObject.objectId)")
        } else {
            NSLog("%@", error)
        }
    }
    dbId = cardObject.objectId
```

I couldn't get objectId, how can I get it?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Why couldn't you get `objectId`?  Did you get some kind of error?

Comment: It's what Christian Woerz said.

Comment: It too me a minute to understand what happens inside of a block. The block only executes the code inside of it once the background task has completed. But the rest of your code will continue to run. So when you have that fetch outside of it it's pulling the data, most likely, before the save occurs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the name of your function already says, it is a function which is called asynchron. That means that the main thread doesn't wait for the function to finish. So you will get an (still) empty objectId.

To get your objectID after saveInBackground is finished, you have to put your line where you get the ID into the if-clause.

```
 var cardObject = PFObject(className: "YourCard")
    cardObject["cardNumber"] = cardNumber
    cardObject["balance"] = balance
    cardObject["expire"] = date
    cardObject["validFlg"] = cardStatus
    cardObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if (success != nil) {
            NSLog("Object created with id: \(cardObject.objectId)")
            //Gets called if save was done properly
            dbId = cardObject.objectId

        } else {
            NSLog("%@", error)
        }
    }
```

Another option would be to call `save()` in the main thread. That way the function finishes before you call the objectId. Parse doesn't recommend that, but it's a possibility:

```
cardObject.save()
dbId = cardObject.objectId
```